# Mysql группировка

Tags: mysql

Подскажите почему сбивается сортировка в подзапросе. То есть после подзапроса выборка опять неотсортированная и группировка уже проводится не так как нужно.

Есть табличка юзеров у каждого юзера может быть несколько статусов.Так вот мне нужно взять максимальный статус юзера и сгруппировать по юзерам. Поэтому и пытался сперва отсортировать и потом сгруппировать.Но вот на деле все иначе вышло

```
user1 1
user2 1
user1 2
user2 2
```

Тоесть на выходе я ожидал получить 2-ой статус по каждому юзеру.Задача то элементарная но вот непонятно почему так отрабатывает сортировка в подзапросе.

```
SELECT * FROM(
SELECT *
FROM users
ORDER BY id DESC
) as a
GROUP BY a.users
```

Comment: Что значит "группировка проводится не так как нужно". Группировке фиолетово какой порядок записей, она просто собирает все записи с одинаковым условием группировки в одну строку. при этом попытка использовать какие либо другие поля, кроме указанных в group by и заключенных в агрегатные функции (sum, count, и т.п.) в большинстве БД запрещена. В MySQL это можно но вернется случайное значение колонки, никто не гарантирует что вернется например первое значение. поэтому сортировка не имеет никакого смысла

Comment: А посему лучше опишите задачу, чего вы пытались достичь таким запросом. Скорее всего вашу задачу надо решать совсем другими методами

Comment: поправил вопрос

Comment: Ну если максимальный id то - `select users, max(id) from users group by users`. но что то мне подсказывает, что вы чего то не договариваете ...

Comment: Ну смотрите я ожидал что после сортировки я получу последние занесенные статусы юзера,и группировкой возьму по каждому юзеру первую запись.

Comment: Тогда приглядитесь к тому ответу, ссылку на который я вам дал, там делается примерно то же самое. В вашем случае запрос из того ответа будет перефразирован примерно как `select * from users where id in(select max(id) from users group by users)` ну или то же самое с помощью join (как в том ответе)

Comment: Хорошо,только поясните мне если можно почему после выполнения подзапроса список перестает быть отсортированным по id по убыванию?

Comment: А на будущее запомните - если вы используете группировку то в запросе вы можете получить чистыми только те колонки, которые перечислены в group by, ко всем остальным вы _обязаны_ явно применить агрегатные функции. Во всех остальных случаях результат не предсказуем хоть с сортировкой, хоть без нее. И в новых версиях MySQL подобный запрос вообще вернет ошибку

Comment: Он не перестает быть отсортированным. MySQL _не гарантирует_, что вернет первое значение для колонки без агрегатной функции. Указание таких колонок в новых версиях MySQL (как и в подавляющем большинстве других СУБД) _запрещено_. group by всегда выполняет собственную сортировку что бы выполнить свою работу и при этом не обращает внимания на то, в каком порядке записи были до этого